# New Symfony UX Live Components work but aren't updated interactively

Tags: php, symfony

I've been asked by a client to look into Symfony UX's [Live Components](https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-live-component/current/index.html) for use in an internal project. We/they are away of its alpha status and the fact that it will likely change and break over time so no need to point that out.

The thing is: I got everything working but the Live Components just act like regular Twig Components that don't actually update interactively without a refresh of the page. I've gone so far as to literally take an example from the documentation in an attempt to get it running, but it just won't update. Is anyone familiar with these components able to point out what I might have done wrong?

First off, I've included the component in Composer:

```json
    "require": {
        ...
        "symfony/ux-live-component": "^2.4",
        ...
    }
```

`package.json` contains the required stuff as well:

```json
    "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.0.0",
        "@symfony/stimulus-bridge": "^3.2.0",
        "@symfony/ux-live-component": "file:vendor/symfony/ux-live-component/assets",
        ...
    }
```

The Stimulus bridge is enabled in my webpack config:

```js
Encore.enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')
```

And I've included its bootstrap file in my main JS file:

```js
import './bootstrap';
```

Finally I made this component and template:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Component;

use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\Attribute\AsLiveComponent;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\Attribute\LiveProp;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\DefaultActionTrait;

#[AsLiveComponent('random_number')]
class RandomNumberComponent
{
    use DefaultActionTrait;

    #[LiveProp(writable: true)]
    public int $max = 1000;

    public function getRandomNumber(): int
    {
        return rand(0, $this->max);
    }
}
```

```
<div {{ attributes }}>
    <p>Random number: <strong>{{ this.randomNumber }}</strong></p>
    <p>Generating a number between 0 and {{ max }}</p>

    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label>Max</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" data-model="max">
    </div>

    <button data-action="live#$render" class="btn btn-primary">Generate a new number!</button>
</div>
```

Clicking the button or changing the value of the input has no effect. When I refresh the page I do get a different random number though, so the component itself is working, it's just the asynchronous part that is not.

My javascript console is fairly useless, there are no errors or warnings, just some logging from Stimulus itself which seems to suggest that at least Stimulus itself is working as intended:

```
application #starting <stimulus.js:1683>
application #start <stimulus.js:1683>
```

Is anyone here familiar enough with this new tech to point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had this exact issue today. From your logs it seems that the Stimulus controller is not being loaded.

Make sure your `controllers.json` file contains the controller:

```
{
    "controllers": {
        "@symfony/ux-live-component": {
            "typed": {
                "enabled": true,
                "fetch": "eager",
                "autoimport": {
                    "@symfony/ux-live-component/styles/live.css": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "entrypoints": []
}
```

Also your `bootstrap.js` should contain the following:

```
import { startStimulusApp } from '@symfony/stimulus-bridge';

// Registers Stimulus controllers from controllers.json and in the controllers/ directory
export const app = startStimulusApp(require.context(
  '@symfony/stimulus-bridge/lazy-controller-loader!./controllers',
  true,
  /\.(j|t)sx?$/
));
```

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the issue. My bootstrap file was correct but the controllers file missed the Symfony UX part. I can't find any mention of this in the documentation by the way, did I miss something obvious?

Comment: I agree, it should be part of the documentation. I think they didn't bother adding it, since the symfony flex script automatically adds the controller when you install the composer package. At least it does, if you have the standard setup.

Comment: I had to do just one more thing after doing this and checking with question and this answer, but I needed to update my encore. I was on 1.1. I think the latest version at time of writing was 4

yarn/npm dependencies using yarn upgrade @symfony/webpack-encore 
or npm upgrade @symfony/webpack-encore

Comment: i tried the change to the `controllers.json`, but it did not work ... i had to replace `typed` by `live`